# how to construct json input data for amazon personalize

Tags: python, json

according to the doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/batch-data-upload.html
I need to construct a json file for batch recommendation.

I tried doing this:

```
batch_prediction_user_id = pd.DataFrame({'userId': range(0,5)})
result =batch_prediction_user_id.to_json(orient="records")
```

I got

```
'[{"userId":0},{"userId":1},{"userId":2},{"userId":3},{"userId":4}]'
```

this result is str, how can add a new line after each userId, so that I can get something like this

```
{"userId": "4638"}
{"userId": "663"}
{"userId": "3384"}
...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
batch_prediction_user_id = pd.DataFrame({'userId': range(0,5)})
result =batch_prediction_user_id.to_json(orient="records")

print(result.replace(",","\n"))
```

output:-

```
[{"userId":0}
 {"userId":1}
 {"userId":2}
 {"userId":3}
 {"userId":4}]
```

use `replace()` function use replace "," with "\n"